C++ queue manipulation problem without C++ 20
I want to manipulate a queue of multi dimensional array (matrice), I am not interested in std since my cross compiler is not fully supporting C++20
queue<float**> q; 
float A[2][3] = {{0, 1, 2}, {10, 20, 30}}; 
printf("Value from array %f\n", A[1][1]);
q.push( (float**) A );
printf("Array A added to the queue \n");
printf("Value from the queue %f\n", q.front()[1][1]); 

Here's the output:
Value from array 20.000000
Array A added to the queue 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I also tried with queue<float*> q;
queue<float*> q; 
float A[2][3] = {{0, 1, 2}, {10, 20, 30}}; 
printf("Value from array %f\n", A[1][0]);
q.push( (float*) A );
printf("Array A added to the queue \n");
printf("Value from the queue %f\n", ((float**)q.front())[1][1]);

I an getting the sane result

A float ** is not a 2 d array, although it can be used in a couple of ways to simulate one. q.push( (float**) A ); is broken.

Thank you, but please answer with the right way to do it, if you cam

my cross compile is not fully supporting C++20 --  Why mention C++20?  You don't need C++20 to create a coherent matrix class that doesn't resort to using float**.   A matrix class can be created using just std::vector<float>, and if not that, a std::vector<std::vector<float>>.

but please answer with the right way to do it -- See the Array2D class.  Then std::queue<Array2D<float>>.

Thank you both, I think I will used the cv::Mat since it's already present in my project

Search the internet for "C++ FAQ Matrix".

Just remember that whenever you see "raw pointers" in current C++, you have to ask yourself. Who "owns" that pointer. Because even if your float** would be queued it would point to something on the stack that's long gone by the time you use it later.
That's why in current C++ you never see "owning raw pointers" anymore. As for arrays you can use std::array/std::vector in C++ or as mentioned if your array models a "concept" like a matrix, use a matrix class.  (@PaulMcKenzie : that's also why I do not really like using Array2D here, since it is semantically a matrix not an array)

Never use C-style casts. Use the C++-style casts instead or rely on implicit casting. Had you tried to use static_cast instead the compiler would have told you that this is wrong.

@NassimMOUALEK IMHO cv::Mat is a very decent choice for a multi dimentional array. The data is also reference-counted and cv::Mat is easily moved/copied around by value.

The error is because of the fact that float[2][3] cannot be directly converted into float**.float** means it expects an array of float*.
If you want to use directly it in queue , you can use a pointer to the array itself and declare queue as holding pointers of array of size [2][3] in this format
queue<float(*)[3]>q;
queue<float(*)[3]> q; 
float A[2][3] = {{0, 1, 2}, {10, 20, 30}}; 
printf("Value from array %f\n", A[1][1]);
q.push(A);
printf("Array A added to the queue \n");
printf("Value from the queue %f\n", q.front()[1][1]);

This gives the output as
Output:
